# maze solving breadth-first-search algorithm in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, breadth-first-search

I'm trying on implementing an breadth first algorithm, that solves a labyrinth. As an input I have a n*m binary matrix, where '1' stands for obstacle/wall and '0' for path/ free cell.

I'm struggling with how to store and proceed the information in matlab. So basically I start with my start cell, and check all it's direct neighbours for obstacles. If they are free, I mark them as a potential path, and then I do the same recursively for all those cells again.

Please help me if anyone had an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have an idea of how to implement an algorithm, but check out Djikstra's algorithm for a simple method of solving the problem.

As for MATLAB, I have simply used a series of matrices to represent the information for each cell. With Djikstra's algorithm, you start with a single open node, check its neighbours and compute the path cost to each one, then move on to the neighbour with the lowest cost. The trick is to set nodes you have visited to be closed, set neighbours you've checked to be open, and leave unchecked nodes as unknown.

Here is my code, which runs based on an image of the obstacles where free cells are white and obstacle cells are black. So you can open a simple paint program like MSPaint and draw maps very easily. Then just change the filename at the top of the code accordingly.

You can see the the use of the variable open_map, where it contains a value for each node, that can be:

1 - open

0 - unvisited

-1 - closed

-2 - obstacle (same as -1 in terms of the algorithm, but -2 is handy for plotting)

```
% read map file
map_file = 'obstacle_map.png';
obstacleMap = imread(map_file);
obstacleMap = 1 - obstacleMap(:,:,1)';

% get map size
Ni = size(obstacleMap,1);
Nj = size(obstacleMap,2);

% set initial position node
i0 = 1;
j0 = 1;

% set target position node
iTrg = Ni;
jTrg = Nj;

% initialize open node map, and close obstacle nodes
open_map = zeros(Ni,Nj);
open_map = open_map - 2*double(obstacleMap);

% initialize best score map
f_score = 0*ones(Ni,Nj);

% initialize previous node maps
Iprev = zeros(Ni,Nj);
Jprev = zeros(Ni,Nj);

% start open map with initial position node open
open_map(i0,j0) = 1;
is_open = 1;

% skip this many frames during plotting
Ngtf = 100;

% keep searching while there are open nodes
count = 0;
while is_open > 0;

    % loop counter
    count = count + 1;

    % find open node with the lowest score
    F_score = f_score + (1e9)*(open_map ~= 1);      % take the scores and add some big number to nodes that aren't open
    [ic,jc] = find(F_score == min(min(F_score)));

    % we might have more than one with the lowest score, so just take the
    % first candidate
    ic = ic(1);
    jc = jc(1);    

    % exit if we reach the target node
    if (ic == iTrg) && (jc == jTrg);
        break;
    end

    % set the current node to be closed
    open_map(ic,jc) = -1;

    % for each neighbour of the current node
    for i = (ic-1):(ic+1);

        % don't try checking neighbours out of bounds
        if i < 1 || i > Ni;
            continue;
        end

        for j = (jc-1):(jc+1);

            % don't try checking neighbours out of bounds
            if j < 1 || j > Nj;
                continue;
            end

            % skip if the neighbour has already been visited (i.e., it is
            % closed)
            if open_map(i,j) < 0;
                continue;
            end

            % compute the new best score to the neighbour (the best
            % score to the current node plus the distance to the neighbour
            % node from the currend node)
            f_score_new = f_score(ic,jc) + sqrt((i - ic)^2 + (j - jc)^2);

            % if the new best score is less than the previous best score
            % for the neighbour node, or the neighbour node has never been
            % checked
            if open_map(i,j) ~= 1 || f_score_new < f_score(i,j);

                % set the previous node indices (keep track of the actual
                % path)
                Iprev(i,j) = ic;
                Jprev(i,j) = jc;

                % update the new score
                f_score(i,j) = f_score_new;

                % set the neighbour node to be open
                open_map(i,j) = 1;
            end

        end
    end

    % plotting
    curr_map = open_map;
    curr_map(ic,jc) = 2;
    if mod(count,Ngtf) == 0;
        clf;
        surf(curr_map,'edgealpha',0);
        axis equal
        view(2)
        getframe;
    end

    % check how many nodes are open
    is_open = sum(sum(open_map == 1));

end

% final plotting map
final_map = open_map;

% final node
iF = ic;
jF = jc;

% backtrack through the list of previous nodes to construct the final path
ipath = [];
jpath = [];
while 1;
    final_map(iF,jF) = 2;
    if iF == i0 && jF == j0;
        break;
    end
    iprev = Iprev(iF,jF);
    jprev = Jprev(iF,jF);
    ipath = [iprev ipath];
    jpath = [jprev jpath];
    iF = iprev;
    jF = jprev;     
end


clf;
surf(final_map,'edgealpha',0);
hold on;
plot3(jpath,ipath,100000*ones(size(ipath)),'k.-');
axis equal
view(2)
```